# Differences between Geoserver 2.15.0 and 2.11.0

Tags: geoserver, wfs, json

I was doing a GetFeature request call to a WFS service in Geoserver in json format with my application. I had initially installed 2.11.0, then when I moved to 2.15.0 my app stopped running,

I have discovered that the header response in the json is different depending on the Geoserver version I'm using,

In 2.11.0:
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":56,"features":[

In 2.15.0:
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[

So the number of total features is missing,

What Geoserver configuration step am I missing in order to get the same response?

Comment: which version of wfs are you requesting in each case?

Comment: VERSION=1.1.0. same version request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is still there, just further along the list of attributes.

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"tasmania_cities.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[147.291,-42.851]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"CITY_NAME":"Hobart","ADMIN_NAME":"Tasmania","CNTRY_NAME":"Australia","STATUS":"Provincial capital","POP_CLASS":"100,000 to 250,000"}}],**"totalFeatures":1**,"numberMatched":1,"numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2019-03-19T15:37:22.888Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"}}}